# How to add and update a column in dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I've got a dataframe with millions of records and I want to add a new column and update it in spark using scala based on some condition as shown below :

```
uid       date  code
1   20-05-2016     a
1   21-05-2016     b
1   22-05-2016     c
2   21-05-2016     a
2   23-06-2016     c
2   24-06-2016     b
2   24-06-2016     c
2   25-06-2016     d
```

I want to add a column to assign subid in such a way that each time code reaches c for a particular uid, the subid is incremented by 1 for that uid. So the resultant data frame would be something like :

```
uid       date  code  subid
1   20-05-2016     a      1
1   21-05-2016     b      1
1   22-05-2016     c      1
2   21-05-2016     a      1
2   23-06-2016     c      1
2   24-06-2016     b      2
2   24-06-2016     c      2
2   25-06-2016     d      3
```

i.e. we start assigning each uid by 1, after we reach a c for the same uid, we increment the subid by 1 and assign 2 and so on.

Now, the challenge here is:
1) I need to make sure that each subset of unique uid are not divided into different nodes else it could break the logic so 
2) I read that frame specification in window functions is not supported in hive [as shown here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-windows.html).

Any suggestions how to achieve this whilst ensuring that i manage to cater to the volume of the dataframe and also that a all rows of an unique uid are processed on a single node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark-SQL Window functions on Dataframe - Finding first timestamp in a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315840/spark-sql-window-functions-on-dataframe-finding-first-timestamp-in-a-group)

Comment: @zero323 Although, it should work in a similar way, unlike the solution given, we need to increment the subid on every occurence of code 'c', that is imperative